# Change the dataframe string columns to datetime format yyymm format

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with two columns in string format. [image]

I want to create two more column in the date format yyyymm. So for example- for the first column "Start_date*", I need the variable start_date_yymm which is basically the yyyymm format of the first column. I want to do this while keeping all other variable.

| Start_date | end_date | start_date_yymm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 21:11:00 | 2016-01-02 01:37:00 | 201601 |

Code that i am using

```
df[["START_DATE*","END_DATE*"]]=df[["START_DATE*","END_DATE*"]].apply(pd.to_datetime,format="%m/%Y",errors="coerce")
```

but unfortunately i am not getting the desired results

Comment: `df['start_date_yymm'] = df['START_DATE*'].dt.strftime('%Y%m')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strftime`?

```
df['start_date_yymm'] = df['START_DATE*'].dt.strftime('%Y%m')
df['end_date_yymm'] = df['END_DATE*'].dt.strftime('%Y%m')
```

Or if `START_DATE*` and `END_DATE*` are strings:

```
df['start_date_yymm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE*']).dt.strftime('%Y%m')
df['end_date_yymm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['END_DATE*']).dt.strftime('%Y%m')
```

**Update**: single operation:

```
df[['start_date_yymm', 'end_date_yymm']] = df[['START_DATE*', 'END_DATE*']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.strftime('%Y%m'))
```

Comment: Is it what you expect?

Comment: @corralien- Yes, thank you , but i was just wondering if this could be done in a single step rather than doing this seprately